# mean median and mode dictionary list python 3

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mean

I need to calculate the mean, median and mode of the name of a London Borough. I have created a dictionary list and tried importing the statistics functions to work it out.

```
n = [
{'name': 'Barking and Dagenham', 'length': 19.0},
{'name': 'Barnet', 'length': 6.0},
{'name': 'Bexley', 'length': 6.0},
]
```

I tried this:

```
mean_l = mean(n['lenght'])
print('The mean length of the name of a London Borough is', mean_l)
```

however it keeps on giving me the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is the code that raised the error? dictionary `n` is defined properly.

Comment: mean_l = mean(n['lenght'])
    print('The mean length of the name of a London Borough is', mean_l)

Comment: That's not how indexing works.

Comment: That is because `n` is a list of dictionaries, not a dictionary. You need to iterator over the list.

Comment: provide the full code please... Where does `mean` come from? Which module are you `import`ing? And put it directly to the question; not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: I have imported mean from statistics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work. Create a list containing all lengths, then apply the appropriate statistical function to that list.

```
import numpy as np
import statistics

lengths = [x['length'] for x in n]

mean_length = np.mean(lengths)
median_length = np.median(lengths)
mode_length = statistics.mode(lengths)
```

Comment: However numpy hasn't got an attribute for mode. What shall I use instead?

Comment: The statistics module has a mode function, I will update my answer.

Comment: It solved it. Thank you! I can see where I've gone wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling your list `n` the way you expect it. When you write

```
n[x]
```

then python will try to look at position `x` in the list. If you now do

```
n['length']
```

then python doesn't know what to do, because there is no position `'length'` in your list. You can do

```
n[0]['length']
```

because the elements in your list (indexed with integers) are dictionaries. I think you can solve this by creating a list that only consists of the values for the length field like so:

```
length_list = [d['length'] for d in n]
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it because you spelled length wrong the second time so it's calling it wrong